# Updating twitter status from php

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I am working on a PHP project where I want to be able to post things automatically to twitter.

From my PHP program I have authorised my twitter app and stored the oauth_token and verifier in a mysql database.

When the user submits a form, it is supposed to post the data to twitter. To do this I am retrieving the oauth_token from the database to post the message but when I look at the response before the section of code that does actual status update I get an error saying

> 'invalid/expired token'

Below is the code I am using

```
function postToTwitter($twitterMsg)
    {
    require ("../../social/phpHandler/twitterLib/EpiCurl.php");
    require ("../../social/phpHandler/twitterLib/EpiOAuth.php");
    require ("../../social/phpHandler/twitterLib/EpiTwitter.php");
    require ("../../social/phpHandler/twitterLib/secret.php");

    $query = "SELECT * FROM social_sites";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if ($result)
    {
        //session_start();
        //$twitterObj = new EpiTwitter($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
        while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $oauth_token = $myrow['token'];
            $verifier = $myrow['verifier'];

            $twitterObj = new EpiTwitter($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
                $twitterObj->setToken($oauth_token);
            //echo 'OAuth Token: ' . $_GET['oauth_token'];
            $token = $twitterObj->getAccessToken();
            $twitterObj->setToken($token->oauth_token, $token->oauth_token_secret);
            $_SESSION['ot'] = $token->oauth_token;
            $_SESSION['ots'] = $token->oauth_token_secret;
            $twitterInfo= $twitterObj->get_accountVerify_credentials();
            $twitterInfo->response;
            //echo '<pre>';
            print_r($twitterInfo->response);

        }
    }
```

### Update

I've exported the `$twitterInfo` variable and written it to a file and the output is below. Not sure if this helps at all.

> EpiTwitterJson::__set_state(array(    'resp' =>
>   EpiCurlManager::__set_state(array(
>        'key' => 'Resource id #12',
>        'epiCurl' => 
>       EpiCurl::__set_state(array(
>          'mc' => NULL,
>          'msgs' => NULL,
>          'running' => NULL,
>          'requests' => 
>         array (
>           'Resource id #11' => NULL,
>           'Resource id #12' => NULL,
>         ),
>          'responses' => 
>         array (
>           'Resource id #11' => 
>           array (
>             'data' => '    Invalid / expired Token
>   /oauth/access_token  ',
>             'code' => 401,
>             'time' => 0.39,
>             'length' => 136,
>             'type' => 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
>           ),
>           'Resource id #12' => 
>           array (
>             'data' => '{"error":"Invalid \/ expired Token","request":"\/account\/verify_credentials.json"}',
>             'code' => 401,
>             'time' => 0.156,
>             'length' => 83,
>             'type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
>           ),
>         ),
>          'properties' => 
>         array (
>           'code' => 2097154,
>           'time' => 3145731,
>           'length' => 3145743,
>           'type' => 1048594,
>         ),
>       )),   )),    'responseText' => '{"error":"Invalid \/ expired Token","request":"\/account\/verify_credentials.json"}',
>   'response' =>    array (
>       'error' => 'Invalid / expired Token',
>       'request' => '/account/verify_credentials.json',   ),    'error' => 'Invalid / expired Token',    'request' => '/account/verify_credentials.json', ))

### Update 2

I've tried saving the access token by serialising the object and storing it in the database using the code below

```
function authenticate($consumer_key, $consumer_secret)
    {
        $twitterObj = new EpiTwitter($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);

        $twitterObj->setToken($_GET['oauth_token']);
        //echo 'OAuth Token: ' . $_GET['oauth_token'];
        $token = $twitterObj->getAccessToken();
        $twitterObj->setToken($token->oauth_token, $token->oauth_token_secret);
        $_SESSION['ot'] = $token->oauth_token;
        $_SESSION['ots'] = $token->oauth_token_secret;
        $twitterInfo= $twitterObj->get_accountVerify_credentials();
        $twitterInfo->response;
        //echo '<pre>';
        //print_r($twitterInfo->response);
        //var_dump($twitterInfo);
        $username = $twitterInfo->screen_name;
        $profilePic = $twitterInfo->profile_image_url;

        addToDatabase($username, $profilePic, $_GET['oauth_token'], $_GET['oauth_verifier']);
    }

    function addToDatabase($username, $profilePic, $token, $verifier)
    {
        $token_serialised = serialize($token);
        $query = "INSERT INTO social_sites (social_name, token, verifier, username, profilePicture) VALUES ('Twitter', '$token_serialised', '$verifier', "
            . "'$username', '$profilePic')";
```

Then later on, I'm trying to post to twitter without it having to reload the twitter app authorise page by getting the value from the database I saved earlier and unserialising it to post to twitter using the following code:

```
$twitterObj = new EpiTwitter($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
            while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                //$access_token = unserialize($myrow['token']);
                //$twitterObj->setToken($access_token);
                //$token = $twitterObj->getAccessToken();
                $token = unserialize($myrow['token']);
                $twitterObj->setToken($token->oauth_token, $token->oauth_token_secret);
                $_SESSION['ot'] = $token->oauth_token;
                $_SESSION['ots'] = $token->oauth_token_secret;
                $twitterInfo= $twitterObj->get_accountVerify_credentials();     

                $myFile = "log.txt";
                $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("Error");
                fwrite($fh, var_export($twitterInfo->response, true));
                fclose($fh);

//              $twitterMsg = $_REQUEST['tweet'];
                $update_status = $twitterObj->post_statusesUpdate(array('status' => $twitterMsg));
                $tem = $update_status->response;    
                fwrite($fh, var_export($tem, true));
                fclose($fh);
}
```

The log file writing is where is writing out the twitter response where it is stating that the token is invalid or expired.

### Update 3

I've also noticed that it comes up with a php error when it unserializes it stating

> Notice: unserialize(); error at offset 2555 of 2987 bytes

and when I try to export the variable it appears to be empty

Comment: Are there any exceptions or errors going to your error log?

Comment: No, know errors are thrown as far as I can see, only the twitter response failing

Comment: @Boardy Are you sure that the twitter account you're trying to post to still has this app authorised? I've seen this before and that was the cause in that case.

Comment: @BenGriffiths, yea it is authorised still can see it in the app settings of the twitter account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you storing the oauth_token in the database?

You cannot store it simply as a string as it is an object. Instead you would need to serialize it before writing it to the database, and unserialize it when you retrieve it from the database.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: I'm storing the oauth token a mysql database with the mediumtext data field. I'm guessing this is probably the problem. Is the oauth token the URL parameters that twitter redirects you to after authorisation is this something else as this is what I'm using for the oauth token

Comment: the oauth_token is an object, so you must serialize it before you put it into the database

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation:

1) Use a PHP library like http://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth.

2) Select your app on http://dev.twitter.com/apps and click on "My Access Token".

3) Us that access token as described on http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_single_token.

See More:
[link1](http://davidwalsh.name/update-twitter-php)

[link2](http://blog.cmstutorials.org/reviews/general/how-to-update-your-twitter-status-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

You should create twitter aplication. Download and connect EpiTwitter api. Copy twitter application key and secret(in app settings) use them to init twiiter object.

```
 $twitterObj = new EpiTwitter($context["TWITTER"]["APP_KEY"], $context["TWITTER"]["APP_SECRET"]);
```

then check if twitter already send token to your page or not

```
$oauth_token = $_GET['oauth_token'];
if($oauth_token == '')
{
 $url = $twitterObj->getAuthorizationUrl();
 header("Location: $url");
}else{
 $twitterObj->setToken($_GET['oauth_token']);
 $token = $twitterObj->getAccessToken();
 $twitterObj->setToken($token->oauth_token, $token->oauth_token_secret);
 $_SESSION['ot'] = $token->oauth_token;
 $_SESSION['ots'] = $token->oauth_token_secret;
 $twitterInfo = $twitterObj->get_accountVerify_credentials();
}
```

if twitter token = '' your page make request to twitter and take response with token(response come to address which you type in twitter application settings -redirect field), when you have it, you may change your status like that:

```
 $twitterObj->setToken($_SESSION['ot'], $_SESSION['ots']);
 $update_status = $twitterObj->post_statusesUpdate(array('status' => $tweet_msg));
 $temp = $update_status->response;
```

Comment: Wouldn't this way means that the user would always have to authorise the app from the twitter page. I wanted to do it so the user can add a twitter account to my php program and when they submit a form at any time it automatically authorises and posts the twitter update. Is this not possible

Answer (score 0):

You must escape data before inserting it into MySQL. You can use [mysql_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php) PHP built-in function.

Edit: you should use a library to communicate with the server (Twitter and others) for you. I have written a simple one, you can read about it more in [this blog post](http://geek.daohoangson.com/2010/04/oauth-with-google-twitter-and-facebook.html). It supports Twitter, Facebook and Google.

Comment: Thanks this did work, I wish I could accept your answer as well @lamplightdev as you both resolved the issue.